# How to move the elem in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know Javascript in the beginning level and I need some help.

```
left = '-180px';
$sub_menu.show().animate({'left' : left}, 200);
```

I want to move $sub_menu from the right side to `180px`from his default position before animate it, i.e. to make the indent on the right.

**!!!  EDIT  !!!**

[Here my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kntwj0qj/2/)

For each menu element, on mouseenter, I enlarge the image, and show both `sdt_active` span and `sdt_wrap` span. If the element has a `sub menu` (`sdt_box`), then I slide it - if the element is the last one in the menu I slide it to the left, otherwise to the right. My problem is the last **Menu 6**. It must work as other menus only it should slide to the left on the same width.

Comment: Where is your HTML. The code you have posted is incomplete.

Comment: create a JSFiddle for what you are trying to do, it will allow everyone to help you with better input.

Comment: Did you include jQuery in your project ? For make your instruction, you need to get the actual position of your element like this in JS: `element.style.left` or like this in jQuery $element.position().left

Comment: Why don't you give him left: -180px with CSS, and left: 0 with JS ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are searching for this:

```
$sub_menu.show().animate({ 'left' : '-=180px' }, 200)
```

Comment: I inserted your answer in my updated jsfiddle, but it didn't work

Comment: Your code is working properly, you need to increase the left offset on 6th menu element.

Comment: Yes, my menus work fine except the last one. The 6th sub_menu has the wrong position. Can you please explain me more about increasing the left offset on 6th menu element?

Comment: In your jsfiddle the 6th menu element starts to slide far away right. It is wrong. Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kntwj0qj/7/), here I enlarged the outer container for better view and to slow down animation. I want the 6th menu element start to slide from Menu 6 blue box.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$sub_menu.css('left','-180px');
```

and for animation you can add CSS3 transition code to your CSS3 property

Answer (score 0):

check this http://api.jquery.com/animate/

and you should use this , in your example

```
 $sub_menu.show().animate({ 'left' : '-180px' }, 200);
```

Comment: I have two types of `sub_menu`: the first one slide to the right, the other one to the left. That's why I set `left` outside of `animate`